# Change Font in MUI and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, fonts

Hey there I am working on a little web project and i need to change the font to Oswald (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Oswald). I am using NextJS with MUI for the components

I really dont know how to achieve this. I couldn't find working solutions

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font family with the `theme.typography.fontFamily` property.
look [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/) how should you change font on MUI.

Here an example:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'Oswald, Arial',
  },
});
```

And use it,

```
// ...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Box
      sx={{
        fontFamily: 'Oswald',
      }}
    >
      Oswald Font
    </Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
```